# Jackson JSON conversion rounds values outside of integer range (2^32)

Tags: java, jackson

I'm using jackson to convert my objects into JSON in my spring boot application.
I have the following class I want to automatically convert.

```
public class User {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Long userId;
}
```

This is my spring endpoint where the conversion should happen.

```
@GetMapping("/users")
public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    List<User> users = userService.getAll();
    System.out.println("== Controller==");
    for (User user : users) {
        System.out.println(user.getUserId());
    }
    return users;
}
```

The above code prints the following values:

```
== Controller==
1814323055790927793
4470400760286564824
7161908306709881455
```

However viewing the values inside the browser gives me the following results:

```
1814323055790928000
4470400760286565000
7161908306709882000
```

Which all seem to be rounded versions of the above. I would think it's a precision issue if it weren't that these values should all be able to be stored inside a Long. How do I get Jackson to display the correct values?

Comment: Is that the actual data that is transmitted over the wire or is that some interpretation that the running javascript outputs? Inspect the request in the browser console and check the data there.

Comment: @luk2302 You are correct. It was the interpreting javascript that was doing the rounding. Thanks!